# How to passing data for image src in modal Laravel using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

Hello i need help to pass the data for my src image in modal using jQuery.

```
view.blade.php
@foreach ($users as $user)
 <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
 <button class="btn-success showuser" 
  data-id="{{ $user->id }}" 
  data-userphoto="{{ $user->user_photo }}"
  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-insert">
 <i class="fa fa-pencil"  align="center">Insert Proof</i>
 </button>
@endforeach

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Upload
    $(document).on('click', '.showuser', function() {
    $('#iduser').val($(this).data('id'));
    $('#userphoto').val($(this).data('userphoto'));
    });

});
```

I have id user and userphoto(filename) as data and then i pass it to my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-insert">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="form-group">
 <input type="number" name="id" id="iduser">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="user_photo" id="userphoto">
 <img style="max-width: calc(100% - 20px)" src="/storage/(**contain id="userphoto"**)">
</div>
```

How to make my src can contain the value of id="userphoto" ?
Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery Code, try to use attr function for image

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // Upload
     $(document).on('click', '.showuser', function() {
     $('#iduser').val($(this).data('id'));
     // this part
     $('#userphoto').attr("src"',$(this).data('userphoto'));
   });

});
```

Comment: Hello sir, how to use it in views ? <img id='userphoto'> is this true ?

Comment: How to use it on my modals i mean, src="/storage/(id='userphoto')" like that ?

Comment: hmm, nope. in that case, use it like this $('#userphoto').attr("src"',"/storage/"+$(this).data('userphoto'));

Use developer tools to inspect and debug

Comment: Thanks sir for makes me better. GBU and im going to practice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution could be to grab the data from the button element using jquery (or js) and then inject it in the modal also with your jQuery (or js). I removed some stuff to more clearly show the principle:

Here you have the button passin the userphoto src:

```
<button class="btn-success showuser" data-userphoto="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-hPRwRTQY8o/hqdefault.jpg">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"  align="center">User 1</i>
</button>
```

Then let your jQuery (or js) inject it to your modal (obviously here you can also just send the attribute src to a img element declared in the modal code - there are several ways to make this action):

```
$('.showuser').on('click', function() {
    $('#imagineThisIsYourModal').html('<img src="' + $(this).data('userphoto') + '"/>')
});
```

Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5qmuewkL/1/

I know this is not the complete answer to your question but it show the basic principle I'd use.

Good luck and welcome to stackoverflow!